# Django 1.7 Neither Pillow nor PIL could be imported: No module named Image

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, python-3.x

I am developing an application using Django 1.7 with Python3.4. I have installed Pillow as per the instructions from http://pillow.readthedocs.org. But whenever I try to upload an image from admin I get following error:

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /admin/content/slide/add/

Neither Pillow nor PIL could be imported: No module named Image

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://www.soujanyam.com/admin/content/slide/add/
Django Version:     1.7.2
Exception Type:     ImproperlyConfigured
Exception Value:    

Neither Pillow nor PIL could be imported: No module named Image

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/utils/image.py in _detect_image_library, line 108
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.6
Python Path:    

['/home/ubuntu/websites/sloppyjoe',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
```

Comment: There's clearly something odd with your configuration since your error reports Python version 2.7.6 but the location is in the 3.4 dist-packages. Are you mucking around with sys.path somewhere?

Comment: I did installation of pillow using pip3 and gave dist-packages of python3.4 path in my virtualhost configuration. Apart from that I didn't use anything remaining part is working fine except this Pillow installation.

Comment: @DilipDakshinapu Then it sounds like you installed Pillow for Python 3.4 but are running Django on Python 2.7.6.

Comment: What command do you use to start the development server?  Make sure that the Python binary you use on the command line is the one you intend to use.

Comment: Thank you, Problem solved I was using libapache2-mod-wsgi 3.4 which doesn't support python3.4. I have replaced it with libapache2-mod-wsgi 3.5 it worked.

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3

Above command solved my problem